# unable to zoom my ipad app

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, zooming, meta-tags

I have an ipad app where in the default pinch zoom functionality of ipad is not working.
I have used the following meta tags in my html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any custom plugins, like iScroll etc? They may (and will) affect on default zooming functionality.

Comment: Typically this happens if you base the size of certain elements on the window size (using % values, or using Javascript to set px values based on the window size). When you zoom in on content, the browser reports smaller values for window width, proportional to the amount you've zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=10.0;">`

Comment: maximum-scale is defined to 5.0 by default, so setting this shouldn't help with the actual problem.

Comment: Defined a `DOCTYPE` ??? Maybe you should post more code to help us out... That way we wouldn't be second guessing...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kind of TouchEvent listener registered on your page that could preempt the touches events and cancel them before they reach the safari viewport handling level ?
If there are some, make sure that they do not stop/cancel the propagation of the event.

Comment: well i have not used any touch event till now...i think i shoud use touchpunch.js and try...